# How to display all user profile info in myaccount page wordpress

Tags: users, profiles

I was wandering how to display all user profile info in the myaccount page in wordpress. It only shows Name, Email and Password.

Comment: Where is the My Account page? I don't see it in the admin site. Is it from a plugin e.g. WooCommerce, BuddyPress, something else?

Comment: Myaccount page is from woocommerce.